# asterisk pass params between 2 instances

Tags: asterisk

I need to make transfer from application in one asterisk to application on another asterisk and to pass some ID with it.
Can it be done ?

I am using asterisk 13

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You have following options(i am assuming you are using sip)

1) Use SipAddHeader/SIP_HEADER function on other side.
 http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+sip_header

2) Use callerid number prefix, callerid name or put it as part of DST number when calling.

3) Use jabber or SIPMessage

4) Use CURL function to fire http request/ARI or web server script on other side

Comment: SIP headers is a good solution. I've used that to pass data from Kamailio to Asterisk with good success.